# Replace EDT timezone with ET on Android

Tags: android, date, timezone

I would like to replace the **EDT** timezone string with **ET**. This is the business requirement, event I have a very strong feeling this not possible on Android.

I have the following code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(context.getString(R.string.time_login), Locale.US);

    <string name="time_login">\'Last login:\' MMMM dd, yyyy \'at\' h:mm a z</string>
```

which gives me this result: August 11, 2017 at 3:31 am EDT

All I would like to do is replace the 'EDT' with 'ET'. Does any of you ever made something like this?

Comment: Is that the *only* substitution you need to make?  If so, can you not just put `'ET'` instead of `z` ?  Or are you looking for something broader that works across other time zones?  If so, what do you expect for time zones where abbreviations don't work as they do in the US?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change that information using `DateFormatSymbols`.
I let you the part to define the time zone array, but the structure could be like this:

```
private static DateFormatSymbols sym = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US);

static {
    // Here you call sym.setZoneStrings(array);
    // Check this documentation to see the array format https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#setZoneStrings(java.lang.String[][])
}

private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(context.getString(R.string.time_login), sym);
```